# How to find out the target of bubbled event in Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

In backbone events from items are bubbled up to collections, so while executing this:

```
  var c = new Backbone.Collection([]);
  var item = new Backbone.Model({id:3});

  item.on('ping', function() {
      console.log('PING [ITEM]', this);
  });

  c.add(item);
  c.on('ping', function() {
     console.log('PING [COLLECTION]', this);
  });
```

we'll see both "PING[ITEM]" and "PING[COLLECTION]" printed.
One thing that I'm still failing to understand about event attached to collection - how should I find out on which exactly item bubbled event had happened.

I can see no arguments passed, and context is predictably the collection itself.
I have strong suspicions that this is not possible at all, but in this case I'm actually stuck with understanding why we need that kind of bubbling at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
c.on('ping', function(addedModel, collection) {
```

The 1st argument of the anonymous function is the the **model** that has been added to the collection.

The 2nd argument will be the **actual collection**.